# Does TCP buffers segment even if a previous segment is lost?

Tags: networking

Let's say we have a host A and a host B

I send 5 segment from A to B, with sequence number starting from 100 and each segment is 20 bytes long

If there were no packet lost, then I should expect ACK = 200 from B

but there was a packet lost, B got all segment except the 2nd one

I should get 4 ACK of 120 from B, indicating a lost of 2nd segment

After I resend 2nd segment, what will be the ACK from B, is it gonna be 140 or 200?

If it is 140, then it means B didn't buffer 3rd 4th and 5th segment

If it is 200, then it means B only needs the 2nd segment

which one is the true answer?

Answer (score 0):

The buffering technique of out-of-order packets is not the part of the TCP protocol. So it depends on the receiver's TCP implementation.

In both options, TCP sender will correctly handle the situation.

The technique to deal with out of order packets in Linux TCP is well described here:

`Johannessen, Mads. Investigate reordering in Linux TCP. MS thesis. 2015.`
https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/47651/1/thesis-madsjoh.pdf

According to this research, Linux TCP will probably buffer 3rd, 4th and 5th segments (if there is enough space for it) and reply to retransmission with the ACK = 200.